# Use select for Buttons with dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I use Buttons with dropdowns from `input-group` component in twitter-bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns

**code:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /btn-group -->
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
```

I want when user select an option from the button drop-down menu example: im63.gulfup.com/pETcxK.png the selected option must appear instead of : "payment method" default label.

i know the markup for "select" but when i try to integrate it with "input-group" component it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you explain better what you trying to do ??

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't select' The code that you have is not for selecting, but for clicking of actions.

Comment: yes that what i said, i want to edit this code to use selecting

Comment: You want something, but you don't explain what.... Selecting what ?!? A hamburger ??? Be more specific ....

Comment: Do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/VEKYN/

Comment: i want user to select an option from the button drop-down menu example: http://im63.gulfup.com/pETcxK.png i want it to select a payment method and when he select an option it must appear instead of : "payment method" default lable

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/a8cdntuf/

Comment: So after all this massive description, the user just wants a dropdown select element? I'm going to have to -1 for this :(

Comment: @AndreasFurster no i want it with the input field

Comment: @Lee instead of giving me a -1 try to help or just pass away from this post.

Comment: It's basic HTML markup, you should have known about it

Comment: @Lee i know the basics, and i tried many times to integrate the select option with the input-group but it doesn't work.

Comment: I agree with this time, @Lee. It is a little harder as expected, but he has to describe his question better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Html:**

```
<select class="selectpicker">
    <option>Option one</option>
    <option>THE HAMBURGER!</option>
    <option>Option two or three, depents on how you see it</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".selectpicker").selectpicker();
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a8cdntuf/6/
Plugin: http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: i know this plugin and i used it usually, but i want to integrate it with the input field. so user can select a payment option "Wester Union for example" and the enter the money transfer number in the text field.

Comment: i have problem with Mozilla Firefox it doesn't display "payment method" image from mozilla: http://im87.gulfup.com/XsOjbL.png but it's work normally with chrome: http://im87.gulfup.com/kZ3UBA.png any idea?